# error 156 severity 15 state 1 incorrect syntax near the keyword IF

Tags: .net, sql-server

Error at Line Number 25:
I am writing stored procedure which should return data based on the combination selected by the user. For Example I have 3 different type of filter(City/Area/VendorType). If User selects City=xyz and Area=pqr then result should be all data with City=xyz and Area=pqr only. If None of the option is selected by the user then I am setting value for all 3 parameter is equals to null AND should return all row from the database.
**Note : Above 3 column should always have data in database.**
I have created one [WEBMethod] inside which I am calling this stored procedure using sql connection. And passing all parameters using AJAX jquery.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].spGetVendorbyFilter
                      @PageNumber INT,
                      @PageSize   INT,
                      @city       VARCHAR(200),
                      @area       VARCHAR(200),
                      @vendortype VARCHAR(200)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartRow INT
      DECLARE @EndRow INT

      SET @StartRow = ( ( @PageNumber - 1 ) * @PageSize ) + 1;
      SET @EndRow= @PageNumber * @PageSize;

      WITH Result
           AS (
               SELECT *,
                      Row_number()
                        OVER (
                          ORDER BY VendorID ASC) RowNumber
               FROM   tblVendor

              ) 

     IF (@city IS NOT NULL AND @area IS NULL AND @vendortype IS NULL)
      SELECT *
      FROM  Result where City=@city AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE IF (@city IS NULL AND @area IS NOT NULL AND @vendortype IS NULL)
       SELECT *
      FROM  Result where Area=@area AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE IF (@city IS NULL AND @area IS NULL AND @vendortype IS NOT NULL)
       SELECT *
      FROM  Result where Category=@vendortype AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE IF (@city IS NOT NULL AND @area IS  NOT NULL AND @vendortype IS NULL)
       SELECT *
      FROM  Result where City=@city And Area=@area AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE IF (@city IS NOT NULL AND @area IS NULL AND @vendortype IS NOT NULL)
       SELECT *
      FROM  Result where City=@city And Category=@vendortype AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE IF (@city IS NULL AND @area IS  NOT NULL AND @vendortype IS NOT NULL)
       SELECT *
      FROM  Result where Area=@area And Category=@vendortype AND RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow
     ELSE 
         SELECT *
      FROM  Result WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow and @EndRow

END
```

Comment: Sorry Milan, you cannot use an IF statement to generate a conditional CTE.  Am I right in thinking, you want the parameters Area and VendorType to be optional?

Comment: @Destination - Thanks for your Response. May be you are right. If user select 3 options(City/Area/Vendortype) then it should have data accordingly.and If none of the option is selected then it should display all the data.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `CTE` like that. `CTE` should end with either of these `SELECT/INSERT/DELETE`.

According to your `If` condition when `@city` is `NULL` your `ELSE` condition will fail since you are comparing  `City=@city`. If am not wrong you are looking for this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spgetvendorbyfilter] @PageNumber INT,
                                            @PageSize   INT,
                                            @city       VARCHAR(200),
                                            @area       VARCHAR(200),
                                            @vendortype VARCHAR(200)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartRow INT
      DECLARE @EndRow INT

      SET @StartRow = ( ( @PageNumber - 1 ) * @PageSize ) + 1;
      SET @EndRow= @PageNumber * @PageSize;

      WITH Result
           AS (SELECT *,
                      Row_number()
                        OVER (
                          ORDER BY VendorID ASC) RowNumber
               FROM   tblVendor
               WHERE  ( City = @city
                         OR @city IS NULL )
                      AND ( Area = @area
                             OR @area IS NULL )
                      AND ( Category = @vendortype
                             OR @vendortype IS NULL ))
      SELECT *
      FROM   Result
      WHERE  RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
  END
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually I am new in Stored procedure. Could you please help with correct syntax.

Comment: @MilanGadhiya - Did you try my answer

Comment: I am writing above stored procedure to extract data with different filted combination.

Comment: Yes I have tried your code. it is giving syntax error while passing parameter.(Procedure execution failed
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@PageNumber'.
)  Actually I am writing above stored procedure to extract data with different filtered combination. For Example When user selects City(xyz) and area(pqr). Parameter value should be City=pqr and area=xyz and Vendortype=Null and should return all data with City=pqr and area=xyz. AND if none of the option is selected then it should have all data.

Comment: @MilanGadhiya - check the latest code..

Comment: Still it is giving same error(Procedure execution failed
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@PageNumber') while passing the parameters. Thanks

Comment: How are you calling that procedure ?

Comment: I have created one web service inside which i am calling procedure using sql connection and passing parameters through jquery

Comment: @MilanGadhiya - can you show the exec of procedure call ?

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly which lines of code you want from my side.